Prove that $T$ is not a compact operator.
Let $T:\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the operator defined by,
$$T((x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}})=((y_i)_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}).$$
where
$$
y_{j}=\frac{x_{j}+x_{-j}}{2}, \quad j \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
I want to show $T$ is not a compact operator.
The idea is to take closed unit ball $B_{\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})}$. After some simple computation, we have $T(B_{\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})})\subset B_{\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})}.$
But if we are able to prove that $T(B_{\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})})= B_{\ell_{2}(\mathbb{Z})}$, then it will prove that $T$ is not a compact operator.
I’m not sure how to prove the reverse containment.

It is not true that $T(B_{\ell_2(\Bbb Z)}) = B_{\ell_2(\Bbb Z)}$, so your approach won't work

The thing you're trying to prove isn't true. For instance, everything in the image is symmetric about the $j=0$ position.

One valid approach is to consider the sequence ${T(e_k)}_{k = 1}^\infty$ and note that it has no convergent subsequence

I am having problems in reverse containment other side is true and the calculations were so trivial that's why I didn't include it

Is there any other way to proove that it is not compact

In addition to @BenGrossmann 's good hint, realizing that $T$ is a projection might be helpful.

This is basically as @JonathanZ said, but one can show that $T$ is exactly the projection onto the (infinite-dimensional) subspace of sequences symmetric about the $j = 0$ position. No projection of infinite rank can be compact.

That clears my doubt

@DavidGao no projection of infinite rank can be compact can be shown by riesz lemma

For any compact operator $T$ if $x_n$ tends to $0$ weakly then $\|Tx_n\|\to 0$ (see page 4). Let $\{e_n\}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}).$ By the Bessel inequality $e_n\to 0$  weakly when  $1\le n\to \infty.$ However $$ \|Te_n\|={1\over 2}\|e_n+e_{-n}\|={1\over \sqrt{2}}$$
Remark The conclusion holds for any operator $T$ such that $$\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle \not \to 0$$ In the OP case $\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle ={1\over 2}.$

How you used vessel inequality

$$|x|^2\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_n\rangle |^2$$ Hence $\langle e_n,x\rangle \to 0.$

How to proove your first sentence.

I have added a link where the theorem is proved.

For $\lambda\neq0$, $(T-\lambda I)x=0$ iff $x(-n)=(2\lambda -1)x(n)$. In particular, for $\lambda=1$ we have that
$$N(T-I)=\{x\in\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}): x(-n)=x(n)\}$$
This subspace is not finite dimensional. This implies that $T$ is not a compact operator.

Is there any specific result for compactness of operator using the null space

@RicciTen: yes, if $T$ is a continuous operator in a Banach space $X$, If $T$ is compact, then $\operatorname{dim}(N(T-\lambda I))<\infty$ for any $\lambda\neq0$.

Okay this was helpful +1
